# Remove parent category from permalink but keep breadcrumbs structure

Tags: permalinks

I’m reorganizing a pretty large blog with more than 600 posts.

We have created multiple categories and some of them need to be shown as parent/child in the breadcrumb but not in the permalink.

It’s a travel blog so one parent category is “Things to do” and have multiple child categories like “Monuments” “Museums” “Churchs”

So for the post “Saint Peter’s Basilica” the permalink has to be:
mydomain.com/saint-peters-basilica/
Bus the breadcrumb should display child and parent categories like this:
Home / Things to do / Churchs /

How can I do this?
Thank you so much in advance

Comment: Did you identify a solution to this?